# unable to merge dex after updating to android 3.0.1

Tags: android

**I'm getting this dex merger error even after adding multidex enabled true.. have a look at this code and help me..**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aaryanverma.irac"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4'
    testImplementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:vision:1.0.393'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:vision:1.0.393'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:1.0.355'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
   // implementation group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.4.9'
    //implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpasyncclient', version: '4.1.3'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.5.5'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable multidex, setting the `multidexEnabled` to true isn't the only thing needed if the minsedk version is 19. Check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

If you have an application class you need to make it extend `MultiDexApplication`. If you're already extendind something else you need to call `MultiDex.install(this)` in the `attachBaseContext()` method of the application class.

If you don't have an application class you need to add this to your manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I've added this to my manifest file.. still getting the same error.